# how to sort results by specific values in mysql

Tags: mysql

We have a DB called transaction. It has `user_id`, `date`, `value` and so on. I use pagination in my query also. I have thousands of record in my table which has user_id equal to `2` or other value. put the user_id = 2 at the very last page.
I want to sort the result like this:

sort the results by date but if the user_id= 2 , put all results associated with the user_id= 2 at the end.
to be more clear, I show you what I want in the below.

```
-------------------------------------
| ID | user_id |    date    | ......
-------------------------------------
| 1  | 10      | 2018-10-20 |
-------------------------------------
| 2  | 11      | 2018-10-21 |
-------------------------------------
| 3  | 2       | 2018-10-22 |
-------------------------------------
| 4  | 2       | 2018-10-23 |
```

the results have to be like this:

first:  ID = 2, second: ID = 1, third:  ID = 4, last:   ID = 3

tip *:
I use field function but unfortunately in vain.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(user_id, 2) DESC, date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN user_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    date DESC;
```

I'm not sure if you want each group sorted by date ascending or descending.  If you want ascending date order, then remove the `DESC` keyword at the end of my query.

Comment: Beigelesien. no that doesn't return the proper results. I used pagination in my query. it just return the repeated records.

Comment: Pagination has nothing to do with the contents or order of the result set, only how many of those records are returned at a time.  You should edit your question if you have other requirements.

Comment: plz check it again.

Comment: My query _does_ put user #2 records at the very end of the result set, on the last page.  If you're not seeing this, then maybe your pagination code has some problem.